# Remove leading slash NGINX

Tags: php, regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a double slash in my URL (which is not ideal).

So my app is hit at `//signup`.

Error message:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET //signin""
```

Anyway to change it to just `/signup`?

I have tried the below in the first location block (which is the one catching the proxy).

Maybe something along the lines of the...

```
location /apps/phpauthentication/1 {      
        rewrite  ^\//(.*)/$  /$1 break;  
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /app_dev.php last;
        }
    }
```

Full config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /srv/http/web;
    index app_dev.php index.php index.html;  

    location /apps/phpauthentication/1 {
        rewrite ^\//(.*)/$ /$uri permanent;
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /app_dev.php last;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   app:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Full url is `http://domain.com/apps/phpauthentication/1//signup`?

Comment: At the moment coming from the proxy it appears to be `//signup` as that's the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success with the URI changing on the backend while processing with the following.

```
     location /apps/phpauthentication/1 {
       rewrite ^(.*)//(.*)$ /$1/$2 permanent;  ##First matches double slash and rewrites
       try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;  ##URI is now /apps/1/signup
       if (!-e $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/(.*)$ /app_dev.php last; ## Matches all request that pass from above
       }
```

Now the URL in the browser never changes but the backend server now appears to have a valid path.

Comment: Thanks that works for the above and may accept it. I've managed to get it hitting my backend as just `//signup` but tried this regex https://regex101.com/r/aD9iB7/1 `rewrite ^(.*)\/(.*)$ /$2 permanent;` but no joy? to try rewrite it to `/signup`

Comment: Also what is your setting for merge_slashes? Default is Yes http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes

Comment: It's on, should it be off?

Comment: I have my merge_slashes set to no. It can be set in http or server. However this may cause other issues set this way. I was just curious.